# SQL script can sum the digits of a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table with a column  containing numbers listed from 1 to 100. I want to delete numbers that divide by 3 without any remainder. Who can recommend me a way (script) to do that. Only logic I could make in this problem is that if the sum of digits of a number can divide by 3 that means any number which correspond to that case could be divisible.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and **your** attempt.

Comment: Every developer should know the [modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - it is common to almost every development language (though syntax and usage might differ)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to delete the rows with number divisible completely by 3, you can use built-in modulus function

You could say something like this

```
delete
from myTable
where colNumber%3 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This query should solve your problem

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (id % 3) = 0;
```